# Flag the inappropriate content and not allowing people to add a content?

Tags: 7, rules, flags

I have added a content type called "share", I have given the user permissions for this content type, meaning he can add the content and he can share to any one..

If any user feels that the content is inappropriate, he can flag the content accordingly.  If a piece of content is flagged 3 times, the content is automatically unpublished.. I have done this using the Rules module...

But here what I want is if a user's content is unpublished as "inappropriate", the next time he should not be able to post any content but he can still access the site.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I would look into using rules again.

You are going to need a way of identifying users who should not be able to post. Set a rule to apply a flag to the users account once one of their nodes has been flagged 3 times.

Then use this flag in another rule as an IF to only apply it to said user, then maybe either redirect the users who access node/add pages to a page with a custom warning message or try another form of disabling the node creation. Please see below

> Event:
>   Content going to be saved / Accessing a page
>
> Conditions:
>   User is flagged with "suspended user"
>
> Actions:
>   Page Redirect
>   Show a message on the site

EDIT: Am I correct in assuming you are wanting users to flag a node inappropriate? You should be able to use something like the rule you have already created to do so, just also flag the node author when you flag the content...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But how to identify the user who has been flagged 3 times??????

Comment: ya i have flagged the node, but if content has been flagged three times it should be unpublished it has been done.. but now the problem is if the same user posts the same inappropriate content again and again then problem starts.. so we have to disable the accessing like creating the content, this should happen only when his content has been flagged 3 times as a inappropriate content....

Comment: So cant you just add another action to your existing rule which unpublishes nodes? Add "Flag a user" and apply it to node author. Then when they come to create content another rule checks to see if a user has said flag... if they do they are redirected with a custom message...

Comment: if i am creating any other rules they are not linking....meaning if i create first rule then it is working..if i create second rule then first rule will not be in action and second rules is in action...........

Comment: Go into your existing Rule, in the actions where you have DO unpublish node, add another action "Flag a user", select the new user as "contents author" then select the user flag (call it suspended user or something). That is part of your initial rule. Now create a new rule as above.